# d3.csv unable to go up one directory

Tags: javascript, d3.js, navigation

I am trying to reference a file located in the parent folder using d3.csv and I am not able to find the correct syntax.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
root
└── js
    ├── data.csv
    └── myGraph.js
```

Inside the js folder I have myGraph.js. In this file I have the following piece of code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
   data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.date = parseDate(d.date);
   d.close = +d.close;
});
```

If I place my data.csv inside the js folder everything works fine. However, if I move the data.csv file up in the root folder

```
root
├── data.csv
└── js       
    └── myGraph.js
```

and change the code to this then it stops working:

```
d3.csv("/../data.csv", function(error, data)
```

I have also tried:

```
d3.csv("../data.csv", function(error, data)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and what the correct syntax is? Many thanks.

Comment: What server are you using to serve the files locally?

Comment: Good point. I am not using a local server - could that be the reason? I am simply storing all of the files on my local windows machine. I was expecting that since windows allows the use of .. in command line it will also work with javascript - I presume this is the problem. If you reply by saying that this can only work with a server installed I will mark the answer as correct thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Robert - There are a couple of things to work through to get this to work:

1) Due to browser security models, you cannot directly reference/load files on your local machine from the browser by directly specifying either an absolute or relative path to files in your local directories. You have to use a local webserver to serve up your files and make them accessible to the browser (or you upload them somewhere where you have a URL which you can specify in the `d3.csv` call... but that would be tedious).

2) Usually, you can run basic HTTP servers in the directory that contains your `.js` and `.html` files. For example, if you have Python 3 installed system wide, you can start an HTTP server in a directory from the commandline using `python -m http.server`. Then you can access your site at `http://localhost:8000` Unfortunately, this basic server only serves files within the directory it is launched in and doesn't allow for relative path references to other files outside the directory it was launched in. To achieve this, you would need to run a more capable/flexible local webserver that can be setup to allow relative path based referencing of files across a bunch of folders.

It is a bit tedious, but it makes sense why browsers are designed to not allow direct access to local files.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer  - much appreciated.